# the return value of sprintf affecting array

Tags: c, return-value, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

 unsigned char array[]={0xff,0xd8,0xff,0xe0};
 char names[7];
 int count=1;
  sprintf(names,"%03d.jpg",count);
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
   printf("%#x  ",array[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
 return 0;
}
```

the character array is effecting by the  return value of sprintf  which 7 here. I used gdb to find this error. 
How to get rid of this problem and also 
 what to know  what is happening after sprintf line execution. ###

```
output should be : 0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe0
but Output I got is : 0 0xd8 0xff 0xe0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sprintf(names, "%03d.jpg", count);
```

stores the string `"001.jpg"` in `names`, as you would have found out by printing it after the `sprintf`. That string takes 8 bytes to store due to the NUL character, not seven, so you have undefined behavior. In this specific case, the NUL is written to `array[0]` which happens to be adjacent to `names` in memory.

Comment: This is answer I am waiting for. which one is allocated first either array or string(names) first in the memory.

Comment: @wattreader: that depends on the platform/compiler. On my box, the program actually produced the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You have a buffer overrun which is corrupting memory.

The string `"001.jpg"` requires 8 characters (remember the 0-terminator) but your `names` array only has space for 7. The 8th character overwrites parts of `array`, causing undefined behavior.

Make it `char names[32]` or something.